# "App not installed" on one device

Tags: android, installation, failed-installation

I have a problem I ran into these days...

I built a signed android app with **signing version 1 and 2**. The **code has no errors** and the **build tests are all successful**. I had some test devices to install the APK on:

- Samsung Galaxy A3 with Android 6.0.1 (no problem when installing)
- Google Pixel with Android 8.1.0 (no problem)
- Some emulators with different Android versions from 5.1 to 7.1.1
- OnePlus 6 with Android 8.1.0 ("App not installed")

Since the notification "App not installed" gives not much information, it could nearly mean everything. I already tried **uninstalling the debug app** and **installing the signed apk**, still no success.
**Trusted source** is on for the file manager I used, so that is not the problem.

Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check you apps list in setting because may you not installed app completely. If before installed

Comment: No, I used version 4.4... and I don't think it has somethint to do with the build process, since the same apk worked on all of the other devices, only the OnePlus 6 has problems

Comment: so release apk worked on all devices except some devices. am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: have you installed app before on those devices?

Comment: On all except the OnePlus 6, I only installed one version of the app on the OnePlus 6 yesterday, and today, I uninstalled the old version and installed the new version. The old version was unsigned, and made no problems while installing...

Comment: okay check applist in setting . May be app not uninstalled completely from device. open app detail and uninstall for all users

Comment: you can see partially uninstalled app at end in list

Comment: For private reasons, I don't have the OnePlus at my desk, I can try this in like 3 hours...

Comment: okay no problem :-)

Comment: I uninstalled the app and made sure it is removed completely. But nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

It worked after clearing cache and deleting app data.